# hammerJs and kineticJs sensitivity issue?

Tags: javascript, rotation, kineticjs, puzzle, hammer.js

i am using the latest version of both kineticJs and HammerJs, i have an preview picture as i am doing my puzzle game, i now able to rotate my puzzle pieces but the sensitivity of the preview image is very sensitive after my code for the rotation of the puzzle, any way i could bring down the sensitivity of the preview picture??

```
       var image = new Kinetic.Image({
        image : imageObj,
        draggable : true,
        x: stage.getWidth()/4,
        y: stage.getHeight()/4,
        width: stage.getWidth() / 2,
        height: stage.getHeight() / 2,
        visible: false,
    });
    layer.draw();

    var startScale = 1;
    var startRotate = 0;

    var hammertime = Hammer(image);
    hammertime.on("transformstart", function(e) {
    startScale = image.scaleX();
    startRotate = image.rotation();
    }).on("transformstart", function(e){
           image.scale({
        x : startScale * e.gesture.scale,
        y : startScale * e.gesture.scale,
        });
        image.rotation(startRotate + e.gesture.rotation);
        image.image.on("dragstart", function(){
                    image.moveToTop();
                    });
        layer.draw();
    });
    layer.add(image);
```

My fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e70n2693/34/